# MySQL regexp on Indexes

Tags: mysql

I have query having multiple regexp in where clause. The coloumns contained in the where clause have already been indexed.
But the query is not using the indexes.
Does MySql regexp cause use of indexes ? If not, what could be the workaround for this ?

Answer (score 6):

No, a regular expression lookup can't use an index.  If the thing to which you're applying the regex is an index, it might go a bit faster, but you're essentially table scanning.

The only workaround I know is to use `LIKE 'foo%'` instead of `RLIKE 'foo.*'` if that's your regex.  An index on such a column can use the LIKE but not the RLIKE

Comment: Thanks David. This is exactly what i wanted to confirm..
But ,  have already worked with 'LIKE'.
My problem is that i want to search on the both sides. Test can be at any position in the field.

So, the query is LIKE '%foo%'. Is there any way to make indexes work in such a case ?


Thanks 
Vivek

Comment: This is correct. If you can narrow down using a LIKE "constant%", that clause will atleast use an index to already narrow down the results.

Comment: @Vivek unfortunately no.  As it turns out, I was working on exactly the same thing recently, trying to cleverly cache the results of `LIKE '%foo%'` because an index can't help that.

Comment: *"The only workaround I know"* adding a FULL TEXT index and using a FULL text search in a derived table  can also a valid workaround  to limit that regex search from not having to scan that complete table more or less like  `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ... WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST(..) ) a WHERE a.some_columns REGEX ...`

Comment: ....  You just have to sure you write that `MATCH(...) AGAINST(..)` filter not to strict more or less means it the regex is `word|word2` that  `MATCH(...) AGAINST(..)` also atleast returns that.. But this is a very simply example for the more complex regexes this can become a challenge .. Also it might require tweaking the full text settings to allow single letters aswell..