# impact of database Index on regular expression queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database, indexing

Database indices are meant for making lookup faster , But how about the performance of a query which uses a regular expression in where clause on a column which is indexed.

Say we have a table `FILES` which has a field `FILE_NAME` and we have a index created on FILE_NAME.

Then we have a query for searching files with matching name patterns

```
SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE FILE_NAME RLIKE regexp
```

Is creating index on FILE_NAME will help improving performance of above query ??

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808371/mysql-regexp-on-indexes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it *may* improve the performance - but not the way you think.

In normal usage an index allows the DBMS to find rows in a table without scanning through each entry - it can skip over some (for range comparisons, specific values and partial matches such as `LIKE 'ABC%'` but *not* for a query with `LIKE '%XYZ'`). When you try to find rows using some transformation of the data (despite the syntax, RLIKE is a function based on the operands rathe than an operator) the DBMS must apply the transformation to each row of the table. Some DBMS (e.g. Oracle) support function based indexes, hence as long as your regex is constant you could defines an index based on a regex match - MariaDB supports virtual columns which can be indexed which amounts to the same thing.

Hence using an index here won't reduce the number of rows the DBMS has to fetch in order to filter the query.

However, if the number of matches is low relative to the number of rows in the underlying data, and the width of the index is relatively small to the width of the table rows, then the DBMS can identify matching rows by reading from the index - which will be faster and require fewer I/O operations than reading the table rows. OTOH if the index is not massively more compact than the table it represents and the index is not covering (i.e. all terms in the query can be satisfied from the index) you will get worse performance than without the index - since the DBMS must perfom an additional seek and read operation after each match to get to the data - indeed, it's likely the DBMS will never use such an index without an explicit hint.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. A where clause with a regexp won't use an index for the column. However, a index will work for a `LIKE 'foo%'`, so you may use that for narrowing the results.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are some options...
PostgreSQL has a module called pg_trgm for fast similiarity search, including regex search. It offers trigram based indexes."Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.3, these index types also support index searches for regular-expression matches (~ and ~* operators)".  PostgreSQL regexes are actually quite powerful.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html

Lucene is a free library which does this, if you consider it a database. Lucene can create multiple types of indexes for the same value and when a regex search is performed it uses them to narrow down the search. The regex is analyzed and, if it is the case a prefix search or suffix search is performed, otherwise a trigram index is used to narrow down the rows.