# Would indexing a text field allow for better performance during a regex search?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

So I have a blog posts table with a `title` field and I would like for users to be able to query posts via this field. For this, constructed a query where the string the user types into the search bar could be anywhere in the `title` field like so:

```
SELECT id, title, body FROM posts
   WHERE title LIKE "%users_query%";
```

**My question is** could indexing the `title` field enhance the performance of the query? My thinking is at scale when there can be millions of posts, this search would take a very long time and thus indexing the field would decrease response time.

I have taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896935/impact-of-database-index-on-regular-expression-queries-in-mysql) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808371/mysql-regexp-on-indexes) post and they say that indexing won't really make a difference. However they are quite dated so perhaps over time this has become a viable solution.

If this still won't work all too well, what could I potentially do to speed up such queries.

**Side question:** I am also ordering these posts by a `created_at` field descending. Should I index that field as well?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) They are still true, btree simply doesn't support that and MySQL's indexing options are few. [PostgreSQL does with pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html). You could try a [full text index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html), but that isn't quite the same. 2) Yes, you should index created_at. `title LIKE "%users_query%"` will still do a full table scan, but at least it won't have to sort the results.

Answer (score 2):

There are three circumstances where indexing *might* improve that query.

1. If there is no initial wildcard % in the Where.  If your Where clause said `WHERE title LIKE "users_query%"`, then there's a chance you could use the index to pull out only the rows beginning with 'users_query.
2. If you have many rows with the same title.  The index would have fewer rows to run the wildcard against than the table.
3. If the table has an exceptionally large number of columns, it's possible that reading the index would result in a lot less I/O.

Otherwise, yes, it's not worth it.

Comment: If I was to remove the initial wildcard, how much would this realistically improve the query's performance? Would the improvement be worth sacrificing the flexibility that "contains anywhere in the string" gives?

Comment: @darkstar Depends on your application. Referencing my answer below, if you actually wanted to find all the address on bExample Street, then removing the leading `%` would completely remove the ability to make that search. Since you're looking for a blog post title, I don't think it would be a good idea for you to remove the flexibility.

As for performance benefit, it's the difference between a clustered index scan (scan the entire table) and an index seek (return exactly the rows you need), so your mileage will vary depending on how many rows are in your table.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing the title probably won't help. The leading `%` in your query means the search term can appear anywhere in the title, so there is no way for the database engine to seek to the search term.

You can think about it like this - imagine you have the following index on some address:

| address |
| --- |
| 163 pExample Street |
| 276 dExample Street |
| 373 aExample Street |
| 490 tExample Street |
| 512 bExample Street |
| ... |

Now if someone asked you to find addresses on bExample Street, you'd have no choice but to scan the entire index.

Answer (score 1):

LIKE with a leading wildcard (and any REGEX) will check every row.  No indexing helps.

`INDEX(created_at)` together with `ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5` will help *only* if it finds 5 matching rows created recently.  Otherwise, it won't help.

Anyway, `INDEX` cannot handle a `TEXT` columns.  And `INDEX(col(255))`, though possible, limits the search to the first 255 characters.

A `FULLTEXT` index, together with `MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)` can help a lot.  But there are caveats.  Study the manual, then we can discuss some of its difficulties and workarounds.

Limiting an index to just `(title)`, not `(title, msg)` may help some, but not as much as you would like.